# How to reverse elements in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

so as homework i was given a problem that wanted me to Reverse the element in an array.

```
 void main() {

        int myarray[6] = { 12,45,23,123,23,27 };
        int arraylength = 6;
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < arraylength/2; i++)
        {
            temp = myarray[i];
            myarray[i] = myarray[(arraylength - 1) - i];
            myarray[(arraylength - 1) - i] = temp;
            cout << temp;

        }

}
```

anybody knows where i gone wrong ? i can't seem to make it work been trying for quite sometime now

expected output is (27,23,123,23,45,12)

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Do you have to actually reverse the elements or just print them out in reverse order?

Comment: You are printing only one element. Is that intentional?

Comment: What makes you think you are not reversing the elements?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse (although like they said, you have a bad print)

Comment: `std::swap` exists and would turn your loop body into a one liner.

Comment: @beta my bad there il just move the cout inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works fine, what is not working is your output. You need to add a loop that prints all elements of the already reversed array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
   cout << myarray[i] << " ";
}
```

<kbd>[Try Here Online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7820c49c07206dd5)</kbd>

And for the updated loop you need to print `myarray[i]`, not `temp`. And it wont quite work, because your loop iterates only through half of the elements

Comment: This doesn't print the array backwards from last to first.

Comment: The program reveses the elements in the array and the above code prints the resulting array

Comment: It does if the array has been reversed above, which is the case.

Comment: which is a lot of wasted code as you can just iterate backwards to print the array in reverse order.

Comment: @RyanWilson _the problem says to reverse the elements_ which OP's code is already doing

Comment: @KillzoneKid "expected output is (27,23,123,23,45,12)"

Comment: thank you very much @A.A i was never gonna get to this alone thank you very much

Comment: @AhmedHassan But you did most of the work, just the visible part was missing.

Comment: @RyanWilson The output is exactly that (see the link)

Answer (score 2):

Your program is correct but you should use a loop to print all the elements:

```
for(auto x : myarray)
    srd::cout << x << ", ";
```

You can also reverse it using `std::reverse`:

```
int myarray[] {12, 45, 23, 123, 23, 27 };
std::reverse(std::begin(myarray), std::end(myarray));

for(auto e : myarray) 
    std::cout << e << ", ";
```

Answer (score 2):

The reversing algorithm itself is fine, it rotates all the elements around the center thus reversing the array. It is equivalent to using a `std::swap` function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylength / 2; i++) {
    std::swap(myarray[i], myarray[arraylength - i - 1]);
}
```

But you are printing the element **prior** to reversing the array. And you are doing that only half the time due to a `i < arraylength / 2` condition. Reverse the array first and introduce a second `for` loop for printing:

```
for(auto el : myarray)
    std::cout << el << ' ';
```

Or simply use [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) and let the Standard Library do the heavy lifting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int myarray[] = { 12, 45, 23, 123, 23, 27 };
    std::reverse(std::begin(myarray), std::end(myarray));
    for (auto el : myarray) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

That being said the parentheses in `myarray[(arraylength - 1) - i];` is an overkill. You can remove those and have `myarray[arraylength - i - 1];`